# replace any duplicate semi colons with single semi colon

Tags: php, regex

In PHP what is the best way to replace any multiple semi-colons with single semi-colons?

```
xyz;;;;zyx
```

would become

```
 xyz;zyx
```

Comment: preg_replace, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php.  Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

If you know a little bit of RegEx, this can be easily done using the PHP [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

```
<?php 

$text = 'dasd;;;;;;dasdd;;;da;sd;;;;;das;d;;;d;as;d;as;d;;;;;;;';

$replace = preg_replace('/;+/',  ';', $text);

var_dump($replace); // string(30) "dasddasddda;sddas;dd;as;d;as;d"
```